# Regarding complete inner product spaces. (basic real-analysis)

Tags: real-analysis

If I have a point $a$ in a complete inner product space, $H$, can I in theory construct an open ball, $B(a,r)$, that contains the entire complete subset of any closed subset $K\leq H$ ?

Comment: How about if the space is the set of real numbers and the closed set is the set of nonnegative real numbers?

Comment: Is that a problem because the ball can't reach $-\infty$?

Comment: The radius $r$ must be a positive real number, hence any ball is bounded.